# How to fetch data about road vectors to overlay direction arrows in camera view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, augmented-reality, openstreetmap, vector-graphics

I am trying to create a prototype of augmented reality app using html5 and javascript for smartphones. The goal is to show 3d arrows to users on live camera view from source till destination as a route guidance.

I am not clear on how to fetch data about road vectors from either Google Maps or OpenStreetMaps to use in overlaying the arrow. Has anyone done it or tried it ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453682/a-method-to-detect-road-vectors-from-maps is very relevant to my question but it is already closed without any relevant solution. Do i really need vector data or some other technique is also useful ?

Regards,

Wahib

Comment: Maybe some infos can be found there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835623/google-maps-api-getting-street-coordinates, or there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906805/finding-streets-get-their-coordinates-and-calculating-distances-between-marker. Or maybe with using "GDirections"

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far? There are [several possibilities](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Download) of getting road data from OpenStreetMap. If you want to retrieve data for a specific region on the fly the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) might be useful.

A road in OpenStreetMap consists of one or multiple [ways](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements#Way) which are described by [nodes](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements#Node). But not every way is a road, only those which have the [highway](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3ahighway) tag.